# Creating a wallet in non-interactive mode using monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I building wallet software for monero and I'm running into issues of creating wallets from monero private keys. I'm trying to import a private key as a wallet via monero-wallet-cli command, but the command is interactive. Is there a non-interactive mode setting for the cli command? I tried monero-rpc but that doesn't let you import private keys to create a new wallet.

- monero private spend keys stored in mysql database as plain text
- php script that reads the db and runs the monero-wallet-cli command to creat a wallet

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve please? If you have created a wallet, you would have the private keys in a file. Thus you would use the wallet RPC open method on the wallet file (which contains the keys).

Comment: i have a list of private keys that i want to make a wallet for.

Comment: How are they stored though? And what format?

Comment: in plain text. its just the private spend key.

Comment: So a file on disk with hex encoded keys? You commented below MySQL. Please give as much detail as possible instead of drip feeding the question.

Comment: added 2 points to the question. hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Thank you. Jona's answer below seems to have answered the question then.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you can't provide all arguments in the command, but you can pass them via stdin, and "simulate" the interactive process.

If you use `./monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-spend-key walletName`
The cli will ask you for the following arguments in this order:

- private-spend-key
- wallet-password (twice)
- seed-language
- blockchain-height-to-restore-from

You can create a file will all these arguments, each on a new line and tell the cli to read input from this file:

```
$ cat commands 
8106ca36c4206caba03b463e42ba7bf87fd212789c719fd180666d0d9bec230b
myPassword
myPassword
1
0
```

Create wallet:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-spend-key walletName < commands
```

Comment: what if these private keys are in a mysql database?

Comment: You mentioned that a php script reads from the db, so perhaps you should consider run this shell command from the php script. I can't tell you how exactly because I have little knowledge in php, and I also think this is out of the scope of this discussion.